# Compile OpenCL HelloWorld Program: Linker Error

Tags: c, macos, cmake, opencl, codeblocks

My Reference code was taken from "OpenCL Programming Guide" by Aaftab Munshi. The source files for the code can be found at https://github.com/bgaster/opencl-book-samples/tree/master/src/Chapter_2/HelloWorld

I am attempting to run the code on macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.6. Following the instructions in the book, I run the following commands in the folder containing the source files found at the above GitHub link:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../ "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"
```

You need to have cmake installed for the last line to run. The example comes from Chapter 2, pg. 41 of the text. Running the `cmake` generates a Code::Blocks file. When I try to build the Code::Blocks file, I get the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Would anyone know why this error occurs? It seems to be an issue with the build process and not the C syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get cmake to see mac openCL stuff for the LuminanceHDR/opencl branch, I had to do the following (add to CMakeLists.txt):

```
# find OpenCL on Mac
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${OPENCL_Libraries})
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-framework OpenCL -rpath @loader_path/../Frameworks/")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Richard. I added your listing to my script. I now get the following error. Should I change the last line in your listing? `clang: error: no such file or directory: '‚Äú-framework;OpenCL;-rpath;@loader_path/../Frameworks/‚Äú'`

Comment: Yes i think i left off the final end-paren.  Also if you typed it in instead of cut and paste, you might have gotten a curly quote by mistake it appears.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Still get the same error with the amendments.

Comment: Äú Is a curly quote,  you need to change those to be a regular quote: `"`

Comment: Indeed, your initial solution works. I wonder why the author did not include this in the .txt if it was needed. Earlier I tried manually typing the quotes, but I think it was still wrong. Character representation can be tricky :)

Comment: Yes, your system probably has “Smart Quotes” enabled.  To disable, go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Text and uncheck Smart Quotes/Dashes.  Otherwise, when you type a quotation mark, you can immediately hit the space bar to disable the smart quote just for that one character.  Tilde `~` also has a similar "smart" problem in that it will initially come up as an ñ mark unless you hit the space bar to obtain the `~`, which is a representation of the $HOME directory.

Comment: Also, to address your question about why the author did not include the additional cmake directives, there are a few things to note.  The code is 8.5+ years old, and not specifically for macos. Since LuminanceHDR is maintained for Linux, macOS, and Windows, we also separate our system-specific directives with gate codes for each system.

Comment: To do this, we wrap the Mac specific code between `IF(APPLE)` and `ENDIF()` statements. https://github.com/LuminanceHDR/LuminanceHDR/blob/fe5d17674044862164f73ca0ff861ee02dac57af/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Argument `-framework` is usually passed to `target_link_libraries()` (or `link_libraries()`) call and, if it is actually needed, it should be a part of `OpenCL_LIBRARIES` variable, which is filled by `find_package(OpenCL)`. Argument `-rpath` is rarely needed just for building - CMake is smart enough to set RPATH for executables which it builds.

Answer (score 0):

[Instruction installations](https://code.google.com/archive/p/opencl-book-samples/wikis/Installation.wiki) specifically says, that you should build the **entire project** (pass to `cmake` a source directory equal to **top-level directory** of the cloned project).

`CMakeLists.txt`, contained in each example, cannot be built *separately*.

(Look, they miss `cmake_minimum_required()` and `project()` calls, needed by every CMake project; call to `find_project(OpenCL)`, which would set variable `OPENCL_LIBRARIES`, is missed too).

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. I tried directly making the file from the command line at the top level, as outlined in your link, and get the same error: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2` How can I use the `cmake_minimium_required()` and `project()` calls?

Comment: You got the same error, but the command line (`.../c++ ...`) at the end of this error has been changed, hasn't it? Update your question post by adding the exact command line. BTW, before the line `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` it should be the messages with symbols which are not found. They play a great role in debugging (at least, the first of them).

Comment: For me, the command line changed as I used the terminal instead of Code::Blocks to build (I was able to re-produce the original error). "BTW, before the `line ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` it should be the messages with symbols which are not found." ~ Good point. I did not realize it was part of the error.